# Different counting problem by upper/lower case in list matching

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy

```
    Name Text
0   K    IeatApple
1   Y    bananaisdelicious
2   B    orangelikesomething 
3   Q    blueBanana
4   C    appleislike
```

I want to match the 'text' column and list in the data frame.

However, there is no distinction between lowercase and uppercase letters in the'text' column. So, to capture all of them, the list was changed to a regex as follows.

```
mylist = [apple, banana]
mylist = [f"(?i){re.escape(k)}" for k in mylist]
```

```
#contain matching list - column
extracted = df['text'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(mylist)})').apply(set)

#Matched words are added to the data frame as column.
df['matching'] = extracted.str.join(',')

#keyword counting
s = pd.DataFrame(extracted.tolist()).stack().value_counts()
print(s)

Apple 1
Banana 1
banana 1
apple 1
```

One problem with doing this is that it recognizes'apple' and 'Apple' differently.

Is there a way to match both the upper and lower case letters and spell the same word?

Comment: Untested: `extracted = df['text'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(mylist)})', regex=True, case=False).apply(set)`. This probably has a dup question somewhere on SO though =)

Comment: @JvdV got an error : `str_findall() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is convert values to lowercase:

```
mylist = [apple, banana]
mylist = [f"(?i){re.escape(k.lower())}" for k in mylist]

extracted = df['text'].str.lower().str.findall(f'({"|".join(mylist)})').apply(set)
```

Comment: Ah, is it a way to change the 'text' to lower and apply the 'list' to lower?.

Comment: @ybin - edited answer, first 2 rows.

Comment: In my real data, not only English but also Korean is mixed, does it matter whether it is applied? I'll try it once!.

Comment: @Ch3steR - it match, but output is combination lowercase, uppercase.

Comment: @ybin - I guess it should working with all strings, but the best test it.

Comment: ahh yes, didnot notice that. +1

Comment: It works well, thanks always, Joži.